# How do i fix this error in python when trying to use cv2

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning

My problem is i am getting an weird error when trying to run my python code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


PIXELS_EXTENSION = 10


class PuzleSolver:
    def __init__(self, piece_path, background_path):
        self.piece_path = piece_path
        self.background_path = background_path

    def get_position(self):
        template, x_inf, y_sup, y_inf = self.__piece_preprocessing()
        background = self.__background_preprocessing(y_sup, y_inf)

        res = cv2.matchTemplate(background, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
        top_left = max_loc

        origin = x_inf
        end = top_left[0] + PIXELS_EXTENSION

        return end - origin

    def __background_preprocessing(self, y_sup, y_inf):
        background = self.__sobel_operator(self.background_path)
        background = background[y_sup:y_inf, :]
        background = self.__extend_background_boundary(background)
        background = self.__img_to_grayscale(background)

        return background

    def __piece_preprocessing(self):
        img = self.__sobel_operator(self.piece_path)
        x, w, y, h = self.__crop_piece(img)
        template = img[y:h, x:w]

        template = self.__extend_template_boundary(template)
        template = self.__img_to_grayscale(template)

        return template, x, y, h

    def __crop_piece(self, img):
        white_rows = []
        white_columns = []
        r, c = img.shape

        for row in range(r):
            for x in img[row, :]:
                if x != 0:
                    white_rows.append(row)

        for column in range(c):
            for x in img[:, column]:
                if x != 0:
                    white_columns.append(column)

        x = white_columns[0]
        w = white_columns[-1]
        y = white_rows[0]
        h = white_rows[-1]

        return x, w, y, h

    def __extend_template_boundary(self, template):
        extra_border = np.zeros((template.shape[0], PIXELS_EXTENSION), dtype=int)
        template = np.hstack((extra_border, template, extra_border))

        extra_border = np.zeros((PIXELS_EXTENSION, template.shape[1]), dtype=int)
        template = np.vstack((extra_border, template, extra_border))

        return template

    def __extend_background_boundary(self, background):
        extra_border = np.zeros((PIXELS_EXTENSION, background.shape[1]), dtype=int)
        return np.vstack((extra_border, background, extra_border))

    def __sobel_operator(self, img_path):
        scale = 1
        delta = 0
        ddepth = cv2.CV_16S

        img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (3, 3), 0)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        grad_x = cv2.Sobel(gray, ddepth, 1, 0, ksize=3, scale=scale, delta=delta, borderType=cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
        grad_y = cv2.Sobel(gray, ddepth, 0, 1, ksize=3, scale=scale, delta=delta, borderType=cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
        abs_grad_x = cv2.convertScaleAbs(grad_x)
        abs_grad_y = cv2.convertScaleAbs(grad_y)
        grad = cv2.addWeighted(abs_grad_x, 0.5, abs_grad_y, 0.5, 0)

        return grad

    def __img_to_grayscale(self, img):
        tmp_path = "/tmp/sobel.png"
        cv2.imwrite(tmp_path, img)
        return cv2.imread(tmp_path, 0)


solver = PuzleSolver("example/piece.png", "example/background.png")
solution = solver.get_position()

print(solution)
```

The error i am getting:

```
[ WARN:0@0.107] global loadsave.cpp:248 cv::findDecoder imread_('/tmp/sobel.png'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
[ WARN:0@0.111] global loadsave.cpp:248 cv::findDecoder imread_('/tmp/sobel.png'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\solver\solver\main.py", line 102, in <module>
    solution = solver.get_position()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\solver\solver\main.py", line 17, in get_position
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(background, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp:588: error: (-215:Assertion failed) corr.rows <= img.rows + templ.rows - 1 && corr.cols <= img.cols + templ.cols - 1 in function 'cv::cro
ssCorr'
```

I attempted to resolve the problem by reinstalling the packages, hoping that would do the trick, but, alas, no luck. I've followed all the usual troubleshooting steps and checked everything I could think of.

Despite my efforts, the issue persists, and I'm running out of ideas to fix it. Please advise.

Comment: You know what's an excellent idea when you get weird errors? [Showing those errors](/help/how-to-ask). Don't ask people to just guess at what's wrong, guesses aren't answers =)

Comment: You're right haha i don't know how i forgot the most important part @mike-pomax-kamermans

Comment: The problem here is pretty clear.  You do not have a top-level directory called `/tmp`.  You copied this code from a Linux example (where /tmp always exists) and didn't adapt it when you used it on Windows.  Just use a directory that you know exists, like `example/sobel.png`.

Comment: And, by the way, that's a very silly way to convert an image to grayscale.  OpenCV2 has a perfectly fine API to do that without involving the filesystem.

Comment: Hi @Tim Roberts

    def __img_to_grayscale(self, img):
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        return gray

i've used this instead but now i am getting other errors

    def __img_to_grayscale(self, img):
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        return gray

> Invalid number of channels in input image:
>     'VScn::contains(scn)'
> where
>     'scn' is 1

Comment: @iopadupa please remember that comments allow inline code using single back ticks. But also remember that this isn't a competition: don't put code in your comments, [edit] your post to address whatever someone raised in a comment instead, and then go "I've updated my post to address that" instead.

Comment: What that error says is your image is ALREADY grayscale.  You can check for that and skip any modification.

Comment: Okay skipped that now i get

`  res = cv2.matchTemplate(background, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp:1164: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2 in function 'cv::ma
tchTemplate`